# How do I calculate $1.496\,\text{E}11$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Sorry for that noobie question but how do I calculate this type of number $1.496\,\text{E}11$?

Comment: By the way, are you by any chance dealing with an Astronomical Unit (AU) in meters?

Comment: There is scarcely anything to be calculated from the little you have asked about.  The number `1.496 E11` is [E notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation) for $1.496 \times 10^{11}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ 1.496 \times 10^{11}$$

so just move the decimal places to the right by 3 places then tack on 8 zeros to the end.

Comment: so 11 is for the number of zeros after the point?

Comment: https://www.lamission.edu/learningcenter/docs/mathlab/Symbols_Notations/what%20does%20E%20mean%20on%20a%20calculator.pdf

Since you have decimals not at the far right, you have to move those first, then append the remaining powers as zeros, in this case 8, not 11.

Comment: thank you sooo much :)

Comment: @ScarlettLux: Welcome to MSE. :) You can accept the answer by Check marking it. Notice the check mark next to the answer. :)